# curl: no URL specified

Tags: php, api, curl

I trying to learn Laravel 4: [A Start at a RESTful API](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api--net-29785)

I am in half way already, then I face one little problem.

I am stuck at `It's time to test this with another curl request. This one will send a POST request, which will correspond to the store() method created above.`

I ran this command

```
$ curl -i --user firstuser:first_password -d 'url=http://google.com&description=A Search Engine' localhost/laravel-1/public/index.php/api/v1/url
```

I should see sth like this

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 21 May 2013 19:10:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/json

{"error":false,"message":"URL created"}
```

But I see this instead :(

[image]

Is the url is no longer valid ? OR did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: You left out the `http://` prefix. `curl` only adds this automatically if the URL begins with a domain name.

Comment: Ok. It's could be, but It's working with the GET request. Plus, the guy that did the tutorial, he didn't really put the `http://` as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think on Windows you need to use double quotes to quote arguments, not single quotes. As a result, the command is ending after `http://google.com`, everything after that is being treated as a new command, starting with `description`.

```
$ curl -i --user firstuser:first_password -d "url=http://google.com&description=A Search Engine" localhost/laravel-1/public/index.php/api/v1/url
```

The examples in the tutorial you copied from were run on Unix, not Windows. It uses both double and single quotes to quote arguments.

Comment: I tried that, but I face the same messade. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ayqc5fceqzjidt/add%20http%20prefix.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Could you paste text into the question instead of a screenshot? Use the `{}` code tool to mark it as verbatim code.

Comment: `C:\wamp\www\laravel-1
λ curl --user seconduser:second_password -d 'url=http://digitalsurgeons.com&description=A Marketing Agency' localhost/laravel-1/pu
blic/index.php/api/v1/url
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
'description' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I think the problem is your quoting around the `-d` parameter.

Comment: No, I didn't quoting around the `-d` parameter

Comment: I still don't understand what you're saying. Your question clearly shows single quotes around `url=http://google.com&description=A Search Engine`. You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Ohh ok. I got what you're saying now.

Comment: But how's come, I didn't get any feedback like him, `HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 21 May 2013 19:10:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
 
{"error":false,"message":"URL created"}`

Comment: I don't know. Does your webserver log show that the request is being processed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67255/discussion-between-iggy-and-barmar).

Comment: yes this is a problem(?) in Windows. for instance you won't get response for this query: `curl -i -X POST --data 'field1=123&field2=value 2' 'http://localhost:3000'` but instead it is fine with this syntax: `curl -i -X POST --data "field1=123&field2=value 2" "http://localhost:3000"`